# what happens if I update unlocked iphone software?

Tags: ios, iphone, unlock

what happens if I update unlocked iphone software? 
I have iphone 4s with iOS 6.0.1 and I want to update to iOS 8.3 
My iphone was unlocked by [Goguo i-4s v6.1 card](http://3g-sim.com/polysony/index.htm) 
What happens if I do this update or reset my device? Does it re-locked again?

Comment: What do you mean by "unlocked iphone software"?  Can you elaborate?  What's a "Gogou i-4s v6.1 card"?  What specifically do you mean by unlocked?  Are we talking about a software unlock or a hardware unlock?  Was it officially unlocked through your carrier?  Is your phone jailbroken?  Have you tried Gogou customer support or support forums?  What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking and to show us in the question what research you've done.  Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @D.W. it is a typo, it is the Goguo i-4s, a China made method to unlock iphones (illegally I might say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this card only works for iOS 5-6 it is likely that it will not work once you upgrade to iOS 8. According to the website you provided there is a NEW GOGUO V15 Unlock Card which works for iOS 8.